# HTML/CSS: Looking to decorate first 3 lines of a <p> with a left border?

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway for me to insert a left border at the start of a paragraph? Im trying to do it for decorative purposes and wanted to know if this is possible with only HTML and CSS. I've tried a few ways and searched around but have not had any luck.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as a [:before](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp) and then set the height to 3em:

```css
p {
  position:relative;
  padding-left:5px;
}
p:first-child:before {
  content:"";
  background:red;
  display:block;
  width:1px;
  height:3em;
  position:absolute;
  top:3px;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse malesuada ornare dignissim. Proin interdum enim sit amet euismod pellentesque. Aenean et gravida nisl, porttitor pulvinar ligula. Integer convallis, enim a placerat maximus, enim ante placerat elit, at bibendum ex magna et purus. Donec consequat lorem ac urna cursus laoreet. Etiam dapibus sapien vel turpis commodo, vitae congue libero cursus. Suspendisse non congue neque, ut sodales massa. Nullam sollicitudin sem mauris, eu laoreet nisl maximus id. Vivamus dictum dignissim lorem.</p>

<p>Aenean a nisl sagittis tortor molestie dapibus. Integer ornare dictum nulla quis euismod. Vivamus tortor ex, posuere ac nunc in, commodo accumsan massa. Curabitur id massa ut massa cursus luctus ut eu turpis. Phasellus consequat sapien id nisl condimentum bibendum. In ut massa sed enim molestie venenatis. Donec tincidunt gravida nisi, nec mattis tortor euismod nec. Phasellus at sodales nulla, sed sagittis felis. Phasellus quis mauris tempus elit consectetur ultricies.</p>
```

You will probably have to adjust the top value of the `:before`, depending on what font you're using, to make sure it lines up.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some different variants:

```css
.p1:first-letter {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}

.p2 {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p class="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc efficitur sem quis imperdiet tincidunt. Nullam in pulvinar lacus, ut semper purus. Curabitur ut sollicitudin arcu. Aliquam hendrerit mauris eget euismod congue. In vitae ipsum eget lacus facilisis porta nec vel elit. In ex quam, semper a eros in, placerat interdum turpis. Proin tristique elementum velit, auctor dignissim lacus placerat nec. Etiam congue tincidunt ipsum, sit amet elementum risus efficitur quis. Aliquam eget orci leo. Phasellus eget mi blandit, rutrum libero sit amet, consequat ex. Donec vel nisi vitae diam tincidunt consequat. Fusce suscipit laoreet arcu, a pellentesque lectus malesuada porta. Morbi ac justo posuere, pellentesque quam ac, euismod nulla.</p>
<p class="p2">Duis pellentesque mauris eros, non consequat tortor maximus pharetra. Ut quis magna in dui malesuada egestas. Aenean faucibus elit non arcu tincidunt dignissim. Cras ac vestibulum velit. Morbi sagittis dolor in mauris fermentum facilisis. Donec nec libero eu augue dapibus sodales. Phasellus eget ante ligula. Duis vel elit sapien. Aliquam gravida, risus a elementum commodo, ante est feugiat quam, ut consectetur libero tortor vitae quam. Maecenas vel viverra quam, a pellentesque dolor. Donec mattis pharetra euismod. Phasellus non mauris sit amet ligula mattis condimentum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer finibus mauris vitae tellus tristique consectetur.</p>
```